# Export Compliance: Does Parse Server use HTTPS to send all Data or only for Authentication?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, app-store-connect, parse-server

My app uses Parse Server, and Google Places and Google Maps APIs (do the the two Google APIs have any encryption?). But I know parse server uses HTTPS.

So does Parse use HTTPS just for authentication sending data to the DB during signup, login?

Or does it use HTTPS to send data back and forth with the DB always?

I called the Dept. of Commerce today and they said if it was just for authentication that Parse uses HTTPS I didn't have to file anything with them. But, if Parse uses HTTPS for all data being sent back and forth to the DB then I do have to file on snapr or do a yearly report.

Can someone please let me know which it is?

Answer (score 0):

Parse Server always uses the URL scheme in the endpoint you provide. Hence, you are in control of your export control exposure. Only your attorney can advise you on your situation. In my case, I have a SNAPR with BIS.

Comment: Thanks, did you have to wait to get your SNAPR reviewed and cleared before you could submit your app to the app store or google play store? Or could you submit you app prior to getting your SNAPR reviewed (if there is a wait)? Also what kind of lawyer did you engage, this is on the technical side so not sure if a corporate lawyer would be the right kind to ask? Thanks again.

Comment: You need file the SNAPR once. Apple will no longer allow you to ship code through TestFlight without it. Hence, you should just do it. Filing is straightforward. Apple's various docs can help you  If I say much more I would be providing you legal advice.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.